# How to make phone call from custom alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My intent to call the specified phone number from my own skill.

For example

> Me: Alexa, ask <invocation> to find the customer service number
>
> Alexa: Sure, the customer service number is 1800-xxx-xxx-xxx. Would you like to call
>
> Me: Yes
>
> [HOW TO MAKE CALL NOW?]

Comment: @muthupandian Have you got any ideas on the above question?

Comment: no @santhoshkumar

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to open a phone call from your programmed skill (alexa skill service). But for sure you not just want to start the call but also that the user can speak into alexa? But it's not possible to get the voice from the user.

Amazon Alexa transfers the speech input into text.
Your skill service only get JSON requests from the amazon skill interface with intents and spoken things as text.

So there is no chance to the get the audio track from the alexa user. [Also stated in the forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/3071/access-to-alexas-input-speech-audio-for-analysis.html)

- There is a [feature request](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/34670926-add-a-phone-call-feature-in-customized-skill) - you should watch this feature and vote for it.
- Or you implement something like a callbackservice that you interconnect users telephone to service customer number. E.g. via an app on the phone - [see this](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/52659/can-i-make-a-phone-call-using-alexa-voice-service.html)

Comment: Check this video at the bottom of the page [here](https://www.pindrop.com/resources/video/video/alexa-steal-mans-bitcoin/). He states his echo is connected to a custom server instead of Amazon. How might he do this?

Comment: @CoreyCole Interesting video but I don't know how they got the audio into their service for speech recognition. He is not going into technichal details. He was showing to the echo speaker and called it a prototype. Maybe it was a modified speaker (to use their backend directly) but maybe he only refered to the software part.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a call using your echo device or using the Alexa app as long as contact is in your list using [Alexa Calling](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202136150). Calling is only supported in U.S., U.K., Canada, and Mexico.

Here is another link to help you setup

https://au.pcmag.com/gallery/60053/how-to-call-someone-from-your-amazon-echo