# How to make calls using alexa skill

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a custom alexa skill and I would like to know if anyone knows how to make a call using alexa.

I saw a similar question but nobody have answered it yet.
[How to make phone call from custom alexa skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599884/how-to-make-phone-call-from-custom-alexa-skill)

I have a phone number in my api response and I need to call that number using Alexa.

Please let me know if any one knows anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

There are services available that will allow you to place phone calls or send text messages. Twilio and Plivo are a couple that come to mind, but there are many others also.

These services provide APIs, toolkits, and examples to help you interact with them using a plethora of different languages.

Be aware that these are not free, and will charge you per call.